# Number alignment in Python

Tags: python

Instructions: Write a program that generates the multiplication table for numbers 1-10. Use two for loops to complete your program. You will need to put one for loop inside of the other for loop. As an extra challenge, see if you can get the indention to look correct. So the output of your program should be:

[image]

My Code:

```
# Start a for loop from 1 to 10.

for num1 in range(1, 10):

# Start a nested loop from 1 to 10.

    for num2 in range(1, 10):

    # Display the multiplication for each value of num.

        print('%4d'%(num1*num2), end = '')

# Display new line after inner for loop finished.

print()
```

The numbers need to align like in the picture above in the instructions. Mine just shoot straight across the screen. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is what mine look like:

[image]

Comment: You say "Display new line after inner for loop finished." and then have a `print()` statement underneath.  Can you explain what the purpose of that `print()` statement is?

Comment: @Ann The editing is in error. This shows the desired output instead of the actual output under "Here's what mine look like:"

Comment: fixed incorrect edit

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the other image.

Comment: Why not just print ('\n') after the second loop?

Comment: Thanks fro the help! @Ann solution worked best. The other solutions worked as well, but had the numbers spaced out too much. What causes the extra space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
for num1 in range(1, 10):
    print()
    for num2 in range(1, 10):
        if len(str(num1*num2)) == 1:
            print(" "+str(num1*num2),end = ' ')
        else:
            print(str(num1*num2),end = ' ')
```

Output:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 
 3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 
 4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 
 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 
 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 
 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 
 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 
 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to print("\n").

```
# Start a for loop from 1 to 10.

for num1 in range(1, 10):

# Start a nested loop from 1 to 10.

    for num2 in range(1, 10):

    # Display the multiplication for each value of num.

        print('%4d'%(num1*num2), end = '')

    # Display new line after inner for loop finished.

    print("\n") # change made here
```

Comment: this makes unwanted empty line, you should've used "\r" instead of "\n"

Answer (score 1):

> As an extra challenge, see if you can get the indention to look
>   correct.

I believe the following both reproduces the example table the most accurately, with no extra leading or internal spaces, and is the simplest implementation compared to other answers:

```
for row in range(1, 10):
    for col in range(1, 10):
            print(('{:1}' if col == 1 else '{:2}').format(row * col), end=' ')
    print()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 
3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 
4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 
6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 
7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 
>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
for num1 in range(1, 10):
    for num2 in range(1, 10):
        print('%4d'%(num1*num2), end = '')
    print('\r') # this is what I added to your code
```

I added line that prints new line when second loop runs out of elements to print

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds a new-line during the first loop after the second has printed the line. This should match what you need.

```
# Start a for loop from 1 to 10.

for num1 in range(1, 10):

# Start a nested loop from 1 to 10.

    for num2 in range(1, 10):

    # Display the multiplication for each value of num.

      print('%4d'%(num1*num2), end = '')
    print ('\n')
# Display new line after inner for loop finished.
```